# Attempting to open on screen keyboard through another program fails

Tags: windows-10, on-screen-keyboard

I'm using a program called desklock which closes explorer/desktop and blocks hotkeys so that a user can only start programs by buttons on a small window. This will be going in as a touch-screen only HMI system, so I need to be able to launch the on-screen-keyboard. I have a button on the window for this, but whenever I try it, I'm always given the error, simply "could not start on screen keyboard" I've tried launching osk.exe directly, launching a shortcut to it, and launching a script to start it. All three methods work standalone, but when launched by this button, nothing works

Answer (score 0):

If you O.S is a 64bit and you are trying to launch osk.exe from a 32bit application you might experience this problem.
This sould be caused by the File System Redirector which redirects calls to C:\Windows\System32 to C:\Windows\SysWow64.
I have the same problem with the osk.exe in C:\Windows\SysWow64 on Win10.